# MUI AUTOCOMPLETE NOT FILTERING

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

when i type in a part of string into the textfield the options in the dropdown are not getting filtered if i type 112 it doesn't show only values with 112 in them it shows all the options.

```
 <Autocomplete
      disabled={row.group_mapping_id && !('editClicked' in row)}
      freeSolo
      value={row.client_id} 
      onChange={(event, newValue) => props.onChangeTableInput('client_id', index, newValue, row)}
      options={props.clientDetails}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
          if (typeof option === 'string') {
             return option;
          }
          return option.client_id;
     }}
     style={{width: '120px'}}
     disableClearable
     renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} 
                   variant='outlined'
                   inputProps={{
                      ...params.inputProps,
                      autoComplete: "disabled",
                      type: 'search'
                   }} />}
    />
   props.clientDetails ,[
    {client_master_id: 73, client_id: "OM112", client_name: "AOP"},…]
    {client_master_id: 73, client_id: "OH112", client_name: "AKI"}
    {client_master_id: 74, client_id: "OL112", client_name: "AJU2"}
    {client_master_id: 75, client_id: "OLO112", client_name: "ABG4"}
    {client_master_id: 80, client_id: "OM912", client_name: "ACVGh"}
    ]
```

Comment: Did you manage to find out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add filterOptions prop to Autocomplete component
Something like this:
filterOptions={(x) => x}